Scrapy : how to prevent to store duplicates records in the json file
I'm tring to scrap a racing website.from the site i have to scrapp all information of every associated riders to the team.LIsting of the Team is a entry point of the scraping process.
here i have my spider (as i'm using scrapy) which scrap the temas and information of associates riders respectively from different urls
class PromotocrossSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "promotocross"
    allowed_domains = ["mydomain"]
    start_urls = ["mywebsite"]
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
        'FEED_URI': 'promotocross.json',
    }

    def parse(self, response):

        for section in response.css('section.component_breathe'):
            teams_data = {}
            teams_data['team'] = section.css('header h2 a::text').get().strip()
            classes = section.css('div.card_content h3::text').getall()
            dives = section.css('div.grid.grid_breathe').getall()

            for _cls, div in zip(classes, dives):
                _cls = _cls.split(" ")[0]
                teams_data[_cls] = []
                div_selector = scrapy.Selector(text=div, type="html")
                for url in div_selector.css('a::attr("href")'):
                    yield response.follow(url.get(), callback=self.parse_bio,
                                           cb_kwargs={'teams_data': teams_data, '_class': _cls})

    def parse_bio(self, response, teams_data, _class):
        rider_info = dict()
        rider_info['rider_name'] = response.css('div.rider_info h2::text').get().strip()
        rider_info['accomplishments'] = [item.get().strip() for item in response.css('div.s_100.m_50.text_content ul li::text')]
        rider_info['dob'] = response.css('div.s_100.m_50.text_content p::text')[0].get().strip()
        rider_info['city'] = response.css('div.rider_location::text').get().strip().split(",")[0]

        url = response.css('nav.nav.nav_horiz.nav_secondary ul li a')[2].attrib.get('href')
        points_stanging_url = f"https://promotocross.com{url}"
        yield response.follow(points_stanging_url, callback=self.parse_points, cb_kwargs={'rider_info': rider_info, "teams_data":teams_data, "_class":_class})


    def parse_points(self, response,  rider_info, teams_data, _class):

        points_standing_item = {}
        points_standing_item['season'] = []
        points_standing_item['Class'] = []
        points_standing_item['Overall'] = []
        points_standing_item['Points'] = []

        for tr in response.css('tbody tr'):
            tds = tr.css('td')
            points_standing_item['season'].append(tds[0].css('a::text').get().strip())
            points_standing_item['Class'].append(f"{tds[1].css('span.hidden ::text').get().strip()}")
            tds = tr.css('td::text')
            points_standing_item['Overall'].append(tds[1].get().strip())
            points_standing_item['Points'].append(tds[2].get().strip())

        rider_info['points_standing'] = points_standing_item

        url = response.css('nav.nav.nav_horiz.nav_secondary ul li a')[3].attrib.get('href')
        result_url = f"https://promotocross.com{url}"
        yield response.follow(result_url, callback=self.parse_results, cb_kwargs={'rider_info': rider_info, "teams_data":teams_data, "_class":_class})


    def parse_results(self, response,  rider_info, teams_data, _class):

        resuls_item = {}
        resuls_item['Position'] = []
        resuls_item['Race'] = []
        resuls_item['Class'] = []
        resuls_item['Date'] = []
        resuls_item['Bike'] = []

        for tr in response.css('tbody tr'):
            resuls_item['Position'].append(tr.css('td::text')[0].get().strip())
            resuls_item['Race'].append(f"{tr.css('td')[1].css('a span::text').get().strip()}")
            # resuls_item['Date'].append(tr.css('td.sorter-simpleDate::text').get)

        rider_info['results_data'] = resuls_item
        teams_data[_class].append(rider_info)

        yield teams_data

this gives me following response in json file:
[
  {'team' : 'team-1', '450' : [{rider_obj- 1}], '250' : [{rider_obj- 1}]},
  {'team' : 'team-2', '450' : [{rider_obj- 1}], '250' : [{rider_obj- 1}]},
  {'team' : 'team-1', '450' : [{rider_obj- 1}, {rider_obj- 2}], '250' : [{rider_obj- 1}]},
  {'team' : 'team-1', '450' : [{rider_obj- 1}, {rider_obj- 2}], '250' : [{rider_obj- 1}, {rider_obj- 2}, {rider_obj- 3}]}
]

Now, how can i prevent duplicate objects but also get news value of objects. (i.e.
{"team" : "team-1", ...} has three objects but the lat one has all riders appended in the associated class ("450" ,"250")

See this.

Thank you, it's found helpful, but how can I replace those duplicate items instead of just dropping the items? in my case, I have to keep the latest one. Because only in the last I can gather the information of all riders

You might need to implement a custom pipeline probably that doesn't write the output until it has received the last result since it's the only one you are interested in.

I have tried to implement a custom pipeline but I'm clueless here I'm sharing my code
    def __init__(self):
        self.ids_seen = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        adapter = ItemAdapter(item)
        if adapter["team"] in self.ids_seen:
            self.ids_seen.update(item) 
            return item
            # raise DropItem(f"Duplicate item found: {item!r}")
        else:
            self.ids_seen.add(adapter["team"])
            return item

